# Avoiding 429 - Is there a way to incorporate Spotify API "retry-after" response in the API call through Spotipy?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I have a list of thousands of artists (by Spotify ID) and I want to get all of the artists' albums using Spotipy's artists_albums() method.  So the idea is to loop through each artist and make a call to the Spotify API using that method.  However, as there are thousands of artists, Spotify has begun to block my calls resulting in the SpotifyException "Max Retries, reason: too many 429 error responses".

Other than using time.sleep(), is there a more elegant way to prevent too many calls from being made in a 30 second window through Spotipy?  Ideally by taking Spotify's response of "retry-after" and waiting that amount of time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Perform request with multiple ips**
Same thing happend to me when i was working on public API which had some limitations like 50 requests per day. so when my limit is over they block my ip then i make a python script which grab the list of free ips from https://free-proxy-list.net/ and store it in list and start performing request if i get an limit reached error then new ip (next ip) is picked from list

Thise function can scrape those ips and return list of ips

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def GetProxys():
    website_html = requests.get("https://free-proxy-list.net").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website_html, "html.parser")
    soup = soup.find("table")
    Headings = []
    Body = []
    Ip = []
    for heading in soup.find_all("th"):
        Headings.append(heading.text)
    for ip_html in soup.find_all("tr"):
        ip_info_list = []
        for ip_info in ip_html.find_all("td"):
            ip_info_list.append(ip_info.text)
        if len(ip_info_list) > 1:
            if ip_info_list[6] == "yes":
                Ip.append(f"{ip_info_list[0]}:{ip_info_list[1]}")
                Body.append(ip_info_list)
    return Ip, 


Ips = GetProxys()
```

Function which perform request to target api(let http://api.ipify.org which return your requested ip)

```
def perform_request(ip):
    http_proxy = f"http://{ip}"
    https_proxy = f"https://{ip}"

    proxyDict = {
        "http": http_proxy,
        "https": https_proxy,
    }
    try:
       r = requests.get("http://api.ipify.org",
                             proxies=proxyDict, timeout=10)
       print(f"{r}/{r.text}", end="/")
    except:
        print("{-_-}", end="/")
    print()
```

```
for ip in ips:
    perform_request(ip)
```

i think it helps